# Qt XML file -- rearranging nodes

Tags: xml, qt, qtxml

I have to rearrange nodes in XML file. For this i need to copy nodes from `QDomDocument` to another `QDomDocument`.

Original xml file have nodes in this order :--
0,1,2,3,4,5
Now i wan to arrange the nodes in this order :---
0,2,4,1,3,5

1> I am having a XML file which i am reading in an `QDomDocument` (this xml file have 6 nodes).
2> Now I am trying to copy `QDomElement` from one `QDomDocument` & putting them in another QDomDocumentUpdated.
3> Then i am copying the updated `QDomDocumentUpdated` back into xml file.
4> After copying the nodes there are only 3 nodes copied to updated XML document.

Problem I am facing is not all the nodes are copied into `QDomDocumentUpdated`. hence xml file contains less number of nodes than appended by me.

Please suggest how to correct it.

Now as we can see there are 6 nodes in the XML document. Original XML file :---

```
<Animals>
 <Type>
  <Name>Lion</Name>
 </Type>
 <Type>
  <Name>Tiger</Name>
 </Type>
 <Type>
  <Name>Lepord</Name>
 </Type>
 <Type>
  <Name>Bear</Name>
 </Type>
 <Type>
  <Name>Wolf</Name>
 </Type>
 <Type>
  <Name>Camel</Name>
 </Type>
</Animals>
```

Source code file :----

```
QFile   xmlFile;
QTextStream xmlStream;
// xml dom document object
QDomDocument xmlDomDocument;
// xml dom document object
QDomDocument xmlDomDocumentSorted;
QTextStream xmlStream;
QDomNodeList listchildNodes;
QDomNode domNodeChild;
QDomElement xmlRoot;
// xml root for sorted xml
QDomElement xmlRootSorted;


//set the name of the file
xmlFile.setFileName("animals.xml");
xmlFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite|QIODevice::Text);
// Assign file to the stream
xmlStream.setDevice(&xmlFile);

xmlDomDocument.clear();
xmlDomDocument.setContent(&xmlFile);
// Make the root element
xmlRoot = xmlDomDocument.documentElement();
listchildNodes = xmlRoot.childNodes();


/****  Prepare Sorted list ****/
xmlDomDocumentSorted.clear();
// Make the root element
xmlRootSorted = xmlDomDocumentSorted.createElement("Animals");
// Add it to the document
xmlDomDocumentSorted.appendChild(xmlRootSorted);
// Append childs from original document
domNodeChild = listchildNodes.at(0);
xmlRootSorted.appendChild(domNodeChild);
domNodeChild = listchildNodes.at(2);
xmlRootSorted.appendChild(domNodeChild);
domNodeChild = listchildNodes.at(4);
xmlRootSorted.appendChild(domNodeChild);
domNodeChild = listchildNodes.at(1);
xmlRootSorted.appendChild(domNodeChild);
domNodeChild = listchildNodes.at(3);
xmlRootSorted.appendChild(domNodeChild);
domNodeChild = listchildNodes.at(5);
xmlRootSorted.appendChild(domNodeChild);

// Write the updated QDomDocument to XML file
///close file no flush
xmlFile.close();
//set the name of the file
xmlFile.setFileName(xmlFileName);
// open read & write mode
xmlFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite|QIODevice::Truncate|QIODevice::Text);
// Assign file to the stream
xmlStream.setDevice(&xmlFile);

// Write xml to the file
(xmlStream) << xmlDomDocumentSorted.toString();

// close the file
xmlFile.flush();
xmlFile.close();
```

Output XML file :---

```
<Animals>
 <Type>
  <Name>Lion</Name>
 </Type>
 <Type>
  <Name>Bear</Name>
 </Type>
 <Type>
  <Name>Lepord</Name>
 </Type>
</Animals>
```

Please suggest what is missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested your code to see what really happens. I used `QString QDomDocument::toString ( int indent = 1 ) const` to debug.

I did something like this:

```
domNodeChild = listchildNodes.at(0);
xmlRootSorted.appendChild(domNodeChild);

qDebug() << xmlDomDocumentSorted.toString(1);

domNodeChild = listchildNodes.at(2);
xmlRootSorted.appendChild(domNodeChild);

qDebug() << xmlDomDocumentSorted.toString(1);
...
```

and it appeared i have this output:

```
Lion

Lion
Bear

Lion
Bear

Lion
Bear
Lepord
(x3)
```

It seems when you do this: `domNodeChild = listchildNodes.at(x);`, you remove the element from this list.

Let's check the documentation:

`QDomNode &QDomNode::operator=(const QDomNode &n)`

Assigns a copy of n to this DOM node.

The data of the copy is shared (shallow copy): modifying one node will also change the other. If you want to make a deep copy, use cloneNode().

Comment: cloneNode() worked for me ... !!   domNodeChild = listchildNodes.at(x).cloneNode();